# high dimensional broadcast sum

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

In numpy, I have a 4-D array `A` of shape `(10, 10, 5, 5)` and a 2-D array `B` of shape `(10, 5)`.

I want to do two broadcast sum operations.

```py
A[i][.] += B[i][:,np.newaxis]
```

And

```py
A[.][j] += B[j][:,np.newaxis].T
```

Is there any convenient way to do that using NumPy?

Comment: How are `i` and `j` being defined here. What would the resulting shape be? Can you include an abridged version of what your output might look like for some abridged sample of A and B?

Comment: My first guess is `(A + B[:,None,:,None]).sum(axis=0)`.  But I'd need a working example to be sure.